# How to copy all properties from parent to child bean?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a parent-child hierarchy bean, and want to copy over all properties from a parent object to a child.

Thought I could use apache commons `BeanUtils`, which fails. But why?

```
public class ParentChildCopyTest {
    class Person {
        String name;
    }

    class Child extends Person {
        private String birthday;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.name = "Dummy";

        Child c = new Child();
        org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.copyProperties(c, p);
        assertEquals(p.name, c.name); //this FAILS
    }
}
```

Sidenote: of course my realworld object is much more complex. I'm looking for a way to *not* having to copy all properties manually be getter/setter (especially as I don't want to add getter/setter in this specific case).

Answer (score 1):

BeanUtils needs public getter and setter, it won't do anything with private fields.

But you can use reflection, with  Springs ReflectionUtils for example.

This library allows you to read and write private fields.
An example : 
https://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-springs-reflectionutils-to-access-private-fields/

Comment: Yes indeed it works adding getter/setter. So probably I cannot make us of it without them...